# Creating a product with image - Shopify API

Tags: shopify

I am having a problem with image when creating a product using shopify API

Here is the JSON I try to send using POST

```
{
    "product": {
      "title": "Balance 100% Whey Protein 2.8kg w/ FREE Magnesium complete powder",
      "body_html": "<p><span><strong>Balance 100% Whey Protein&nbsp;<strong>&ndash;</strong> WPC/WPI</strong> is your complete protein source providing you with a technically advanced combination of Whey Protein Concentrate, easily-digested Whey Protein Concentrate and Whey Protein Isolate in a 2:1 ratio.</span></p>",
      "vendor": "Balance",
      "product_type": "Physical",
      "images": [
        {
          "attachment": "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",
          "filename": "sample_image0001.jpg"
        }
      ],
      "tags": [
        "Specials",
        "Whey Protein Blend (WPI/WPC)",
        "Protein Powders",
        "Stacks and Packs"
      ]
    }
  }
```

The product is successfully created but the picture wasn't uploaded

Answer (score 0):

The file extension of `filename` parameter must match the filetype of the attached file. Inspecting the attachment, this seems to be a PNG file, while your `filename` specifies a JPG. Change this to match the filetype and it should work.